# PHP get python processes and kill it. Xamp/Windows

Tags: php, python, windows, xampp

How can I get all the python processes along with the arguments of each of process and kill it via PHP Xampp/Windows

Comment: What's wrong with this? http://superuser.com/questions/914782/how-do-you-list-all-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On windows there are three system commands to get processes :

`tasklist`, probably the simplest (though you don't have access to the args).

`get-process`, requires powershell, can't see its output I don't have powershell

And what should satisfy your needs : `wmic process`

So you should run this command using `system()` within PHP so you get the output, then parse it, and when you get the process id, use another system command to kill it :

```
taskkill /PID 99999 #replace 99999 with the process id.
```

Comment: `taskkil /PID 1111 #replace 1111 with httpd process id` ?

Comment: yes, if your process id is 1111 then the command will be : `taskkill /PID 1111`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tasklist` and `taskkill` commands via `shell_exec` function. The following `Task` demonstrate how they can be used to find info about tasks and how to kill them.

```
class Task {
    function __construct($header,$row) {        
        $this->imageName   = $this->findValue($header,$row,'Image Name');
        $this->processID   = $this->findValue($header,$row,'PID');
        $this->commandLine = $this->findValue($header,$row,'Window Title');
    }

    function findValue($header,$row, $key , $default = '') {
        $kk = array_search($key, $header);
        return $key !== -1 ? $row[$kk] : $default;
    }

    public $imageName   = '';
    public $processID   = '';
    public $commandLine = '';

    public function kill(){
        shell_exec( sprintf('taskkill /PID %s',$this->processID));
    }


    public static function findTask($imageName) {
      $csv  = shell_exec(sprintf( 'tasklist /FO CSV /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq %1$s"',$imageName));
      $lines = explode("\n",$csv);
      array_pop($lines);
      if ( count($lines) <= 1 ) {
          return array();
      }      
      $data = array_map('str_getcsv', $lines);

      $tasks = array();
      $header = $data[0];
      for( $kk = 1 ; $kk < count($data); $kk++ ) {
          $row = $data[$kk];
          if ( count($row) === count($header) ) {
              array_push($tasks, new Task($header, $row));
          }     
      }
      return $tasks;
    }
}

foreach( Task::findTask('python.exe') as $task ) {    
    echo sprintf("%s %s %s\n", $task->imageName , $task->processID, $task->commandLine);
    $task->kill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$list = str_replace(' ','|',shell_exec('tasklist'));
$split = explode("\n", $list);
$extension = 'py';
foreach ($split as $item) {
  preg_match_all('#((.*)\.'.$extension.')[\|]+([0-9]+)#',$item, $matches);
  if($matches[1][0] != '' and $matches[3][0] != ''){
    echo $matches[1][0].' '.shell_exec('Taskkill /pid '.$matches[3][0]).PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```